# Groovy: variables in method names with '??' double question marks

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I have this vague recollection reading about groovy that there exists a '??' sugar that can be used to make method names dynamic.  I had thought this is how dynamic finders in grails are achieved, but now I'm question if it was even groovy I'm recalling.  Given the example:
I make a class with some methods

```
class GroovyExample {

  public def getThingOne(){return '1'}

  public def getThingTwo(){return '2'}

  public def getModifiedThingOne(){
    return this.modify(this.thingOne)
  }

  //  *!!!*  I want to get rid of this second modifying method    *!!!*
  public def getModifiedThingTwo(){
    return this.modify(this.thingTwo)
  }

  private def modify(def thing){
    //...
    return modifiedThing
  }

}
```

Is there a `??` sugar for the method name I can use to DRY it up to something like this:

```
class GroovyExample {

  public def getThingOne(){return '1'}

  public def getThingTwo(){return '2'}

  //  Replaced the two getModifiedXX methods with a getModified?? method I think I can do....
  public def getModified??(){
    return this.modify(this."${howeverYouReferenceTheQuestionMarks}")
  }

  private def modify(def thing){
    //...
    return modifiedThing
  }

}
```

The idea being I can call `new GroovyExample().modifiedThingTwo` and get the same answer either way with only one "modification helper method".  Is this possible?  What are the `??` called? (I can't google it for the life of me.)  And, how do I reference the `String` "in" `??`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of that syntax, but you could implement the functionality by implementing `methodMissing()` per [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing).  This is, according to that link, the initial mechanism of action of the dynamic finders you mention (although I believe there is some caching after the first hit on a method) - note the caveats at the top.

Something like this quick test might fit the bill for you:

```
   def methodMissing(String name, args) {
       switch (name) {
           case "getModifiedThingOne":
               return this.modify(this.thingOne)
           case "getModifiedThingTwo":
               return this.modify(this.thingTwo)              
       }
   }
```

Comment: +1 I'd also add `default: throw new MissingMethodException( name, GroovyExample, args )` to the `switch` otherwise it will just return `null` for un-handled method names